# How use of (Switch) instead of (IF & Else) in this sample method

Tags: c#, types, if-statement, switch-statement

I have a mthod by many `if and else`. How can i convert it by `Switch`?

```
protected override IRepository<T> CreateRepository<T>()
{
   if (typeof(T).Equals(typeof(Person)))
      return new PersonRepositoryNh(this, SessionInstance) as IRepository<T>;
   else if (typeof(T).Equals(typeof(Organization)))
      return new OrganizationRepositoryNh(this, SessionInstance) as IRepository<T>;
   else
      return new RepositoryNh<T>(SessionInstance);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664749%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), only sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, string, or enum-types can be used in a `switch` statement, so basically you can not switch on a `type` object.

Now, what you can do is switching on the `Name` of the type, that's just a `string` and it's ok to switch on it.

Comment: Thanks. But use `Name` is Hard Code and is not suitable.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a switch statement for type `Type`.  You can only use a switch with bool, char, string, integral, and enum, or the nullable versions of them.

Per the compiler:

> A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string,
>   integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The `case` statements for a `switch` must be compile-time constants, of type sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, string, or an enum-type (including implicit conversions), and that's not what you have with the `Type` objects.

What is legal:

```
switch (foo)
{
    case 42:
       // code
       break;
}
```

What is not legal:

```
int value = GetValue(); // not a verifiable compile-time constant

switch (foo)
{
     case value: 
         // code
         break;
}
```

Comment: `typeof(something)` is compile time

Comment: `typeof(something)` is also not one of the supported types, nor is it implicitly convertible to one of the supported types.

Answer (score 1):

1. are you sure you want to do it like this? Why not to use object hierarchy and virtual functions?
2. this code works

> ```
> public static void CreateTest<T>()
> {
>     switch (typeof(T).Name)
>     {
>         case "Int32": System.Console.WriteLine("int");
>             break;
>         case "String": System.Console.WriteLine("string");
>             break;
>
>     }
>
> }
>
> static void Main(string[] args)
> {
>     CreateTest<int>();
>     CreateTest<string>();
>     CreateTest<double>();
>
> }
> ```